# PFTableViewCell Jumbled on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I use PFQueryTableViewController to retrieve data from a PFObject.  This is finally successful, however, the textLabel and detailTextLabel are on top of themselves.  Beneath the picture is my code for the cell.  When I used this customCell for just a normal TableView, the text labels were spaced appropriately.

[image]

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1,1,69,69);
    float limgW =  self.imageView.image.size.width;
    if(limgW > 0) {
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,self.textLabel.frame.size.width,self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object` method getting called?

Comment: I finally figured out that I needed to change initWithStyle to initWithCoder.  Issue having now is that the images aren't getting resized into the PFTableCell's imageView properly, everything jumbled on top.

Comment: What do you mean by everything is jumbled on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the frames like this:

```
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,self.textLabel.frame.size.width,self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(74,self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y+self.textLabel.frame.size.height,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width,self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
```

So that the `detailTextLabel` will start after the `textLabel` finishes...

All the best!!!

Comment: Yes, thanks!  The previous code had worked before, so I don't know if it was 8.0 SDK changes or what, but your code nailed it on the head!